# Wrong Unix timestamp since April 2019 in Python 3.7

Tags: python-3.x, unix-timestamp

If, under Python 3.7:

```
from datetime import datetime
datetime(2019, 4, 1).timestamp()
```

I'm getting `1554073200.0`. Shouldn't it be `1554076800.0` instead (i.e. 1 more hour) according to https://www.unixtimeconverter.io/list/2019/april?

I'm getting this error only after 1st April 2019. For instance, if I try:

```
datetime(2019, 3, 31).timestamp()
```

I get `1553990400.0`, which I believe it's the expected result.

I'm using Spyder 3.3.6. Thank you for your help

Comment: I am getting the [right answer](https://repl.it/repls/SpiritedOvalCoins). I can't replicate your issue.  It could my a spyder issue, I would recommend just using native python with and IDE such as VS Code or Pycharm. Spyder adds a lot of bloatware that can cause issues such as poorly made virtual environments and unneeded packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your datetime is "naïve".  It doesn't know what timezone it's in.  The `timestamp` method (as specified in the docs) is assuming you want the local timezone, which in your case has a DST change on the 31st March 2019.  To get the answer you want, you need to set the timezone. For example,

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone
d = datetime(2019,4,1, tzinfo=timezone.utc)
d.timestamp()
```

which gives `1554076800.0` as you expected.